# What's the meaning of "They know every lick and tittle"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

So I watched *Better Call Saul* S04E05, Saul said to his client  "**They know every lick and tittle**" for the answer of "Who is listening in the phone"... I couldn't find the meaning of "lick and tittle" but i guess the Saul means that they know EVERYTHING you talked on the phone, am I right?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: *I couldn't find the meaning of "lick and tittle"* -- where all have you looked and what have you found? Tell us more to help you better. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris It wouldn't do for me to give a definitive reason, but it looks like you've answered your own question there: scanty evidence of research.

Answer (score 1):

Both [*lick*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lick) and [*tittle*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tittle) are easily looked up. ODO has

> An extremely small amount of something abstract
>   A tiny amount or part of something

*Tittle* is a typographic term relating to a small stroke or point; it's a diacritical mark like *á ñ* or *ç* (OED); the word is also applied to the dot on *i*. OED also has "a small quantity, so much as may be had by licking" for *lick.*

In a phrase like "every lick and tittle", the speaker is referring to every tiny part of the conversation; nothing is left out.